# How do I change the url of my website on IIS 10?

Tags: iis

I have .NET MVC application hosted on IIS 10 with the following URL:
https://abc-def-example.com/MyWebsite

I want to use **https://abc-def-example.com** instead of the above URL.

**Note**: MyWebsite is name of an application hosted on IIS

How do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL Rewrite Rule to rewrite the request on https://abc-def-example.com to https://abc-def-example.com/MyWebsite:

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test">
                    <match url="^(?!MyWebsite)(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyWebsite/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Apply this rule to https://abc-def-example.com.

Comment: Hi Ding, I followed your steps but it is not working. URL https://abc-def-example.com is not getting redirected to https://abc-def-example.com/MyWebsite.

Comment: What is the directory structure of .NET MVC application in IIS?